# thread from java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have code with using thread but i don't use thread from java.util.concurrent so i want change my code, but i have some issue.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        doSomething();
                    }
                };
```

I want use executor like this Thread, so how I can do this?Is similar way to do this in java.util.concurrent?I tried that:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //my code doing something
                    }
                };
```

Also I Have:

```
List<Runnable> threadsList = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
```

and I have method:

```
boolean isAllowedCreateNewThread(Runnable taskToRun){
for(int i = 0; i < threadsList.size(); i++){
        Runnable th = threadsList.get(i);
        if(th.isAlive())doSomething(); //isAlive doesn't work since I have runnable instead of Thread
boolean isAllowed = true ;//I have here some bool function but it doesn't matter
    if(isAllowed){
        threadsList.add(taskToRun);
        //service.submit(taskToRun); 
        executorService.execute(taskToRun);
    }
return isAllowed; 
}
```

if I have
    `List<Thread> threadsList = new ArrayList<Thread>();` and don't use ExecutorService and change everywhere Runnable to Thread it work's.
So I think that it also I have to change, but how? What is Keyword insted Thread?Runnable? Or something else? 
Also I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threadsList.size(); i++){
        Thread th = threadsList.get(i);
        if(th.isAlive())doSomething(); myThreadName.start();
```

I have to change `isAlive()` to something similar in `java.util.concurrent` and `myThreadName.start();`
So generally I want change this code using Thread class to code using threads from java.util.concurrent

Comment: I've read your question three times but failed to understand what you're asking. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Change my code using Thread Methods to Methods from java.util.concurrent

Comment: So what have you tried already and which problems did you encounter. "Rewrite my code for me" is not a good question.

Comment: So I think my main question is how I can implement code do this `Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        doSomething();
                    }
                };` is Similar way to do this in java.util.concurrent?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your code with below code segment.

1. Create a Runnable class.

   ```
   class MyRunable implements Runnable{
       public void run() {
           doSomething();
       }
       private void doSomething() {
           System.out.println("Thread Executing is " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a executor service with required number of threads. This creates a pool of required number of threads.

   ```
   int numberOfThreads  = 4;  // number of threads you want to create
   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
   ```
3. Create your Runnable for each thread present in the pool and assign it to your executor.

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++){
       Runnable myRunable = new MyRunable();
       service.submit(myRunable);
   }

   service.shutdown(); // this is a must as not given ,it halts the termination of the program
   ```

   Sample Output

   ```
   Thread Executing is 9
   Thread Executing is 10
   Thread Executing is 8
   Thread Executing is 11
   ```

So the entire code will look like:

```
class MyRunable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Thread Executing is " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfThreads  = 4;  // number of threads you want to create
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++){
            Runnable myRunable = new MyRunable();
            service.submit(myRunable);
        }

        service.shutdown();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Executors* from *java.util.concurren*t.
*Executors* are designed to create and manage Threads, so you don't have to do that directly. 
In your example it would be:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executorService.execute(() -> doSomething());
```

There are many types of *Executors*, and you have to decide which to use considering the context of invocation. 
For instance, if you want to have only one thread, you can use:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

fixed number of Threads i.e. 10:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

or create new threads as needed:

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

For more about Executors you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Hope it helps.